# Is the successor of a limit ordinal undefined?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Suppose $\beta$ is a limit ordinal. Then for all $\gamma < \beta$, $\mathbf{s}(\gamma) < \beta$.

Now I'm wondering if it makes sense to consider $\alpha = \mathbf{s}(\beta)$. If so, $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal as it is a successor ordinal. It seems unintuitive, but I also don't see anything wrong with it, as $\alpha = \beta \cup \{ \beta \}$ appears to be well defined.

Am I missing something here? Cheers.

Comment: The successor of an even integer is an odd integer. Do you find that... odd?

Comment: Look at $\omega+1$ in the second image: http://www.madore.org/~david/weblog/d.2011-09-18.1939.nombres-ordinaux-intro.html

Comment: Horribly confused. You appear to ask if the successor of a limit ordinal is well defined, then go on to say you see nothing wrong it. If you see nothing wrong, then what's the issue?!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: While the questioner has not explained what was worrying him, it seems to me that they may have felt that a limit ordinal ought not to have had a successor because there should be something final about it, perhaps in that when you reach a limit in other contexts you can go no further.

Comment: @PJTraill Perhaps so, but it is no way clear that this is the case or not, hence my vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The successor of a limit ordinal is well-defined: $s(\beta) = \beta \cup \{\beta\}$ where $\beta$ is the limit ordinal.

However, a limit ordinal is not the successor of any ordinal.

Comment: And clearly, the successor of a limit ordinal, is not a limit ordinal?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer when I can. Gotta wait 10 more minutes apparently. :)

Answer (score 9):

In set theory, a function on ordinals is [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function_(set_theory)) if the value of the function at a limit ordinal is the limit of the values of that function on smaller ordinals. If you find the fact that limit ordinals have successors to be counterintuitive, then you seem to be thinking in terms of continuous functions. The successor function is instead a nice example of a discontinuous function on ordinals.